# jquery calculate different values in different element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#run").click(function(){
        var prc = $('.hprc').html();
        var mval = '0.1';
        $('.vprc').html('$'+(prc * mval));
    });
</script>
<table id="form1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="col_label">Col1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col_label">col2</div>
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='pos1' lid1='243' lid2='0' type='checkbox' /><label class='main_cb'>Name1</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='prc'><div class='hprc'>15.00</div>
                <div class='vprc'>$0</div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table width='100%' class='block1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class='pos2' lid1='1' lid2='0' pval='1.00' type='checkbox' /><label class='sec_cb'>Name2</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='prc'><div class='hprc'>1.00</div><div class='vprc'>$0</div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class='pos3' lid1='0' lid2='2401' pval='22.00' type='checkbox' /><label class='sec_cb'>Name3</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='prc'><div class='hprc'>22.00</div><div class='vprc'>$0</div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='pos4' lid1='243' lid2='0' type='checkbox' /><label class='main_cb'>Name4</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='prc'><div class='hprc'>7.00</div><div class='vprc'>$0</div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table width='100%' class='block2' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class='pos5' lid1='193' lid2='0' pval='9.00' type='checkbox' /><label class='sec_cb'>Name5</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='prc'><div class='hprc'>9.00</div><div class='vprc'>$0</div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class='pos6' lid2='1737' lid1='0' pval='19.00' type='checkbox' /><label class='sec_cb'>Name6</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='prc'><div class='hprc'>19.00</div><div class='vprc'>$0</div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type='button' value='calc' id='run'/>
```

The table is generated through php, the count of it's cont can vary.

I am trying to use jquery to calculate, on each line, the value of the class 'hprc' * '0.1'.

It is only calculating the first line and then duplicating the first result for the rest.

Modifying the structure of the table or nameing the classes differently is not an option.

How can I apply the formula for each line?

Comment: Need to run it through a .each()

Comment: you are also missing the `</tr>` of the first row ..

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
// for each item with class prc (the containers)
$('.prc').each(function(){
   var self = $(this),
       mval = 0.1,
       hprc = parseFloat(self.find('.hprc').text()), // get the value of the .hprc element and convert to float number
       vprc = self.find('.vprc');
   vprc.text('$' + (hprc*mval)); // store the result 
});
```

Since you are dealing with prices you could also add `.toFixed(2)` after the calculations to round to 2 decimal digits..

```
vprc.text('$' + (hprc*mval).toFixed(2));
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/uFjQc/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `.each()` function like:

```
var prc = null;

$('.hprc').each(function(){
   prc = $(this).html();
   .....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$("#run").click(function() {
    $('.vprc').html(function() {
        return '$' + ($(this).prev('.hprc').text() * 0.1).toFixed(2);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7GSxS/